# Validating uniqueness on two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model named "Cars"

I wonder how I can declare in the model, so that only one record can exist when two attributes match each other.  For example, in the Car Model

```
:owner_id, :driver_id
```

Let's say a record exists:

```
:id => "1", :owner_id => "22", :driver_id => "23", :state => "parked"
```

If I try to create another record, that also had the same `owner_id` and `driver_id` that matched each other, the record would not be able to create itself. I am trying to make a relation model that will create one record for each owner and driver, when they are matched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Car` model you can define a validation:

```
validates :driver_id, uniqueness: { scope: :owner_id }
```

I believe this should give you the intended behavior, there will be a validation error if you try creating another car with the same driver and owner.